# How do I get to see the contents of my just made .plist?

Tags: xcode, plist

I just made a new file: "VideoNames.plist". Usually the template is shown in the editor. But it is showing up empty. Before updating to Xcode 13.3 I did not have this problem.

When I go and look up the file, the template contents is there.

So how do I convince the editor to show it in plist or xml format?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Right-click > Open As > Source Code

Comment: Thank you, I tried that. It says no file. But the file exists when I check via “Find file in Finder”.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

It turned out that I accidentally had tapped the Enable/Disable Code Review button. Tapping it again brought back my .plist as well as several other missing windows, like fx Assets.xcassets.

Thanks anyway! I appreciate all the good answers, I have found here on this site.[image: CloseUp of the button]